# how to put an array in spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

i have an array

```
private String[] myStringArray = new String[101];
```

how can I use this array to make a spinner?

Comment: What do you mean by spinner?

Comment: http://edumobile.org/android/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/SpinnerExample2.jpg

like this(select a month)

Comment: @user3795343 The page you got that image from has an example of how it is created (which is why it says "example" on it). As the question stands, it's too broad to be answerable in this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `ArrayAdapter`

```
private String[] myStringArray = new String[101];
// populate your array

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerArray);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myStringArray);  
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: in my layout spinner named spinnerArray
how to assign to it?

Comment: The constructor Spinner(int) is undefined.........

Comment: But using code above you are not call any Spinner constructor. You are getting your spinner as declared in layout using findViewById

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole section on Spinners [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html).

You want to create an [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T%5b%5d%29) then set it as the adapter for a Spinner.